# Objective C ==> unichar[] to NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, unichar

I have an array of unichars i need to convert it to nsstring.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`NSString` has a method for that:

[+ (id)stringWithCharacters:(const unichar *)chars length:(NSUInteger)length](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithCharacters:length:)

Comment: Oh, I think this is better than mine

Comment: @vodkhang: it is, yours will fail since the unichar is 16-bits wide

Comment: But how do you get the length of a unichar array? In other words what's the equivalent of `wcslen(foo*)`?

Comment: The links is dead.